# Android : Could Fetch Image From Server Using Volley

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch image from server using volley android but it gives me the following error, can any one tell me what mistake I am doing???
 Here is Single Class:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private Singleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new Singleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }
}
```

Here is my code :

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by PCS on 11/29/2016.
 */
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

   EditText code;
    Button getpic;

    ImageView img;



    Requests rq;

    String ipadd;

    ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    NetworkImageView mNetworkImageView;
    private static final String IMAGE_URL =
            "http://www.catbreedslist.com/uploads/allimg/cat-pictures/Persian-Cat-1.jpg";

    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        ipadd = getResources().getString(R.string.ip);

        code = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.code);
        getpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getpic);



        // Get the NetworkImageView that will display the image.
        mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);

// Get the ImageLoader through your singleton class.
        mImageLoader = Singleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();

// Set the URL of the image that should be loaded into this view, and
// specify the ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.



        getpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl( ipadd +"mem_images.php?code=" +code.getText().toString() , mImageLoader);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

and I am getting this error :

```
12-02 17:51:10.651 9368-9368/com.example.pcs.networkpic I/PhoneWindow: Key up: repeat=0 flags=0x6
12-02 17:51:11.211 9368-9368/com.example.pcs.networkpic I/PhoneWindow: Key up: repeat=0 flags=0x6
12-02 17:51:12.461 9368-9408/com.example.pcs.networkpic E/Volley: [4196] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Request at http://192.168.88.12/mem_images.php?code=9012714 has been redirected to file://database-pc/d/Software/PHOTOS/9012714.JPG
12-02 17:51:12.461 9368-9408/com.example.pcs.networkpic E/Volley: [4196] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.net.url.FtpURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.HttpURLConnection
                                                                  java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.net.url.FtpURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.HttpURLConnection
                                                                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.createConnection(HurlStack.java:169)
                                                                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.openConnection(HurlStack.java:179)
                                                                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:103)
                                                                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
                                                                      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
12-02 17:54:02.781 9368-9369/com.example.pcs.networkpic D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 257K, 7% free 4333K/4620K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 35ms
12-02 18:15:15.051 9368-9368/com.example.pcs.networkpic I/PhoneWindow: Key up: repeat=0 flags=0x8
12-02 18:15:17.811 9368-9368/com.example.pcs.networkpic W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
12-02 18:15:19.871 9368-9372/com.example.pcs.networkpic D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
```